# How to mark a link in a layout menu as "active" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ul filled with links in my layout/application.html.erb and want the current location link be marked with class="active".

Now I'm using:

```
<%= link_to 'About Us', { :controller => 'aboutus' }, :class => "menu#{' active' if params[:controller] == 'aboutus'}" %>
```

But it looks pretty nasty to me.

Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the helper method similar to link_to

its called "link_to_unless_current".

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html ( find the details here )

HTH

Answer (score 14):

The `link_to_unless_current` method doesn't actually create a link, nor does it add a class of active. If you'd still like to do that, you can use the `current_page` method to check if the current page matches the route you specified:

```
<ul id="main_nav">
  <li><%= link_to "Search", search_path, :class => ('active' if current_page?(search_path)) %></li>
</ul>
```

Or if you'd like to add the class on the wrapping element:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(search_path) %>">
  <%= link_to "Search", search_path %>
</li>
```

Comment: Actually in the link_to with :class, the if statement will only print the entire link_to if the condition is true, is not just affecting the class.

Answer (score 0):

An example for a root path with a li tag, i tried to do it with a content_tag, but no luck for the if case in a elegant way

```
<li<%= " class='active'".html_safe if current_page?(root_path) %>>
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
</li>
```

i have some issues when i keep the class in blank with bootstrap(if i remember well)